# validating a sting for decimal input Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to validate user input for correct decimal form like user can enter values like `-123.4` or `123.4` but not `--123.4` or `-.234` or `..234`
Here is what I have done so far but its not working properly

```
var input  = control.value;
       var indexM = input.match((/-/g) || []).length;
       var indexD = input.match((/./g) || []).length;
        if(indexM > 1 || indexD >1  )
         {
        control.value="";
        alert('Invalid Value')
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If acceptable you can just do this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('[id$=txt1]').numeric({ allow: "." });
$('[id$=txt1]').numeric();
 });
```

Where txt1 is the client instance name of the textbox where user is inputting data.

Wrong answer, Delete not working. Cant be used as the same will allow multiple "." and wont allow negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to validate decimal number

```
var input  = control.value;
var exp = /^\-?\d*\.?\d*$/;

if(!exp.test(input))
{
  control.value="";
  alert('Invalid Value')
}
```

Comment: Multiple dots cannot be validated using this.Since the character is still allowed.right ?

Comment: Wrong. it will validate multiple dot. you can check it

Comment: I am checking, its not working for me. I had posted one reply also but further checking that also seems to be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You should should check the user input on each click.

For example: if the input field id='MyInputField" you should use the following code

```
var decimalsRestrictions = function (field) {
$(field).bind("propertychange input", function (e) {
    var resVal = twoDecimalsRestrictions(field.val());
    if (field.val() != resVal) {
        field.val(resVal);
    }
  });
};

 var twoDecimalsRestrictions = function (num) {
   var parts;
   if (num.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
      parts = num.split(".");
      if (parts[1].length > 2) {
          return num.substr(0, num.length - 1);
      }
  }
  return num;
};

decimalsRestrictions("#MyInputField");
```